# Elementary proof that $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, homeomorphism

I was wondering if there were a proof of the fact that $$\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{p_1,\dots,p_n\} \: \text{is not homeomorphic to} \: \mathbb{R}^3$$
for every $n \geq 1$
that does not use cohomology or higher homotopy groups techniques (of course the fundamental group is allowed).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The set of ends of a locally compact space (say locally path connected and path connected) is easy to compute. For $S^d$ minus $n$ points, $d\ge 2$, the number of ends is $n$. Idem for a closed $d$-dimensional manifold minus $n$ points, $d\ge 2$.

Comment: @YCor thank you for the answer! Sorry but I don't understand what do you mean with "ends", can you explain more in detail please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology) I also posted an answer.

Comment: Why is the fundamental group OK, but not higher homotopy groups?

Comment: @LSpice because it is meant for a basic course in Algebraic Topology, which covers only up to the fundamental group

Comment: @LSpice I'd say, because computing fundamental groups is easy using coverings.

Comment: Closing seems a bit drastic. What if the OP had asked instead for a list of different "elementary" proofs? There are many such questions on MO.

Comment: Note that both answers so far show non-homeomorphism, but don't show that these spaces are non-homotopy-equivalent; essentially both rely on a compactification (end compactification vs 1-point compactification). $\mathbf{R}^3$ minus $n$ points is homotopy equivalent to a bouquet of $n$ 2-spheres. I'm not sure how to distinguish these without using $\pi_2$ or second (co)homology, or Euler characteristic (which is $n+1$), which anyway relies on higher (co)homology.

Comment: @YCor Since the case $n=1$ is that $S^2$ is non-contractible a proof that these are not homotopy equivalent implies that $\pi_2 S^2$ is non-zero, so in some sense you need to be able to say something about $\pi_2$... It is hard to imagine any tool from a first course in topology that could do this.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Yes, for famous things like the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: @MikeMiller that's true. About a non-homological approach to non-contractibility of spheres, see [this MathSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237345/how-to-show-sn-is-not-contractible-without-using-homology) In particular, the non-contractibility of $S^2$ is equivalent to the Brouwer fixed point theorem on the 3-ball, which can be shown using analytic methods (yet not that elementary!). See [Analytic proofs of the "hairy ball theorem" and the Brouwer fixed point theorem](https://people.ucsc.edu/~lewis/Math208/hairyball.pdf) by J. Milnor.

Answer (score 41):

The fundamental group of the one-point compactification of $\mathbf R^3 \setminus \{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ is a free group on $n$ generators, for any $n \geq 0$.

Comment: Really interesting, where can I find this result?

Comment: @gigi Prove it! It is a good exercise. Equivalently, this is $S^3$ with $n+1$ distinct points identified. That may help, but the description Dan gives is enough.

Comment: Wow, what a cool fact!

Answer (score 24):

Let $P_n$ be the property for a Hausdorff topological space $X$: for every compact subset $K$ of $X$, there exists a compact subset $L$ of $X$ such that $K\subset L$ and $X-L$ has exactly $n$ components. Obviously $P_n$ is a homeomorphism invariant.

Let $X$ be a compact connected $d$-dimensional manifold, possibly with boundary, minus $n$ points, with $d\ge 2$. One can check elementarily that $X$ satisfies $P_n$ but not $P_{n-1}$. This applies to $\mathbf{R}^{d\ge 2}$ minus $n-1$ points ($=\mathbf{S}^d$ minus $n$ points).

Comment: I'm sure it really is clear, but why does $X$ clearly satisfy $P_n$ but not $P_{n - 1}$?

Comment: I wouldn't say clear, but it's elementary and I think it's more interesting to figure it out than reading a proof.

Comment: +1. It certainly exercises the brain... How did you come up with this?

Comment: @YaakovBaruch: This is just a translation of Yves' earlier comment on the number of ends.

Comment: @‍YCor's earlier [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380557/elementary-proof-that-mathbbr3-setminus-p-1-dots-p-n-is-not-homeomor#comment966628_380557) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380557/elementary-proof-that-mathbbr3-setminus-p-1-dots-p-n-is-not-homeomor#comment966651_380560) by @MoisheKohan.